# Isometric tiles

Tags: unity

I am trying to figure out what is the best way ( in terms of performance) to create a ground to place my 2d isometric sprites on..Should it be tiled ( using 2d sprites ) or just use a plane ( or terrain ) and add a texture to it?

Comment: Depends on what you are looking for besides performance. Purely from a performance stand point, terrain tends to be more memory heavy in Unity.

Comment: @n_palum so go with tiles?

Comment: It's more time consuming but performance it is not as intensive

Comment: @n_palum Do you play Clash of Clans?.If so, aren't those 2d tiles?

Comment: I used to. And yes I believe they are isometric tiles. So they appear 3D but are just 2D

Comment: @n_palum any way I can contact you directly?

Comment: If a textured plane meets your needs, then that sounds like a very simple solution worth trying. If it's not meeting your needs, can you give more details about what additional functionality you're looking for? There are hundreds of games using isometric tiles, implemented dozens of different ways, so it's hard to pick out a "best" approach without more details about what suits your game and your team's preferred workflows.

Comment: ^ What @DMGregory said would be helpful... and I would prefer stuff to stay on here, not direct

Comment: @DMGregory The only use of my ground will be to place buildings on it ( isometric sprites ) and move them so should I go for the plane or tiles?

Comment: You still haven't described a situation that would demand more than a simple textured plane, if all you need is a background to layer sprites in front of. If you have a need that is NOT met by this solution, then you should edit you question to describe this situation. Without a specific problem to solve, there's no compelling reason to recommend any particular solution.

Answer (score -2):

The best way is often *whichever way you prefer*. At the end of the day, you should not have performance issues as a result of dividing your background into smaller pieces. If it suits your design better, do it.